# tablecloth with tablesorter only sorts one way

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

When trying to disable two columns from sorting, this code does that, but the other columns appear to be sorting in just one direction no matter how many times you click.  When you use debug mode you see it is actually sorting twice, the opposite way it was and then back to where you just were.  If you hold the shift key while clicking the headers, it will work correctly.  The tablecloth.js docs say "If you wish to pass custom parameters to the tablesorter plugin, call .tablesorter() on your table object separately" so this is the code I wrote:

```
<script>
    // jQuery Document Ready Function
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("table").tablecloth({
                theme: "default",
                bordered: true,
                striped: true,
                sortable: true
            });
            $("table").tablesorter({ 
                // Turn off some sorting (columns are zero based) 
                headers: {  3: { sorter: false }, 
                            7: { sorter: false } } 
            }); 
        });
    // END jQuery Document Ready Function
</script>
```

Here is the sample table:

```
<TABLE class="tablecloth" style="width:95%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th title="Sort by Client Name" style="background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">Client Name</th>
    <th title="Sort by Rush" style="background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">Rush?</th>
    <th title="Sort by Service" style="background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">Service</th>
    <th style="background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">Requestid/<br>Lineitemid</th>
    <th title="Sort by Name" style="background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">Name</th>
    <th title="Sort by Due Date" style="background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">Due Date</th>
    <th title="Sort by Last Touched" style="background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">Last Touched</th>
    <th style="background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">Notes</th>

</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

      <tr>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>TYCHO</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>

          RUSH!!!!
        </td>            
         <td><font face=arial size=2>OFAC
        </td>

        <td><font face=arial size=2>2126976/<br>10141879</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>LAST NAME,&nbsp;FIRST NAME</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>8/29/2013 1:00:00 PM</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>9/3/2013 10:30:43 AM</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>test</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>LANDSAF</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>
        </td>            
         <td><font face=arial size=2>LDP
        </td>

        <td><font face=arial size=2>2117280/<br>10098096</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>TEST,&nbsp;TEST</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>8/15/2013 1:00:00 PM</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>8/26/2013 12:39:06 PM</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>TEST </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>LANDSAF</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>
        </td>            
         <td><font face=arial size=2>OFAC
        </td>

        <td><font face=arial size=2>2117280/<br>10098097</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>TEST,&nbsp;TEST</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>8/15/2013 1:00:00 PM</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>8/26/2013 12:39:32 PM</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>TEST </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>LANDSAF</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>
        </td>            
         <td><font face=arial size=2>OIG
        </td>

        <td><font face=arial size=2>2117280/<br>10098098</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>TEST,&nbsp;TEST</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>8/15/2013 1:00:00 PM</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>8/26/2013 12:39:46 PM</td>
        <td><font face=arial size=2>TEST </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</TABLE>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used tablecloth, but from looking at the source code, if you set the `sortable` option to `true` it automatically initializes tablesorter.

So, to make them work properly together, leave the `sortable` option as `false`, then just add the class name `headerSortable` to each `th`. Something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1356/)):

If you are using the original version of tablesorter (v2.0.5 from [tablesorter.com](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)), then add the `cssHeader` option as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("table").tablecloth({
        theme: "default",
        bordered: true,
        condensed: true,
        striped: true,
        sortable: false
    });

    $('table').tablesorter({
        cssHeader: 'headerSortable header'
    });
});
```

if you happen to be using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), then the `header` class name in `cssHeaders` should be replaced with `tablesorter-header`

```
cssHeaders : 'headerSortable tablesorter-header',
```

And since you are likely not using the included tablesorter css file, you'll need to include some css to add sorting arrows to the headers:

```
.tablesorter .header,
.tablesorter .tablesorter-header {
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: normal;
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 4px;
    /* black (unsorted) double arrow */
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAJAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAkAAAIXjI+AywnaYnhUMoqt3gZXPmVg94yJVQAAOw==);
    /* white (unsorted) double arrow */
    /* background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAJAIAAAP///////yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAkAAAIXjI+AywnaYnhUMoqt3gZXPmVg94yJVQAAOw==); */
}
.tablesorter thead .headerSortUp,
.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerAsc {
    /* black asc arrow */
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjI8Bya2wnINUMopZAQA7);
    /* white asc arrow */
    /* background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAAP///////yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjI8Bya2wnINUMopZAQA7); */
}
.tablesorter-default thead .headerSortDown,
.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerDesc {
    /* black desc arrow */
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjB+gC+jP2ptn0WskLQA7);
    /* white desc arrow */
    /* background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAAP///////yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjB+gC+jP2ptn0WskLQA7); */
}
```

BUT, since your question has some column sorting disabled, and tablecloth doesn't seem to support this, you'll need to remove those extra header class names from the column. In this case, it is easier to just add the class names before initializing tablesorter (this script will work with both the old and newer versions of tablesorter; [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1360/)):

```
$("table").tablecloth({
  theme: "default",
  bordered: true,
  condensed: true,
  striped: true,
  sortable: false
});

var disabledColumns = [0, 2];

$('table').find('thead th').each(function(i){
    if (disabledColumns.indexOf(i) < 0) {
        $(this).addClass('header headerSortable');
    }
});

$('table').tablesorter({
    cssHeader: '',
    headers: {
        0 : { sorter: false },
        2 : { sorter: false }
    }
});
```